# How can I loop my function?

Tags: jquery

This is a div animation by click. But when the commands end, the function doesn't restarts. I tried with a callback, but perhaps wrong the collocation.

[This is my codepen](http://codepen.io/flipps/pen/NpzQgr):

```js
$(function() {
  //set animation
  $('.fa-arrow-left').on('click', function set_animation() {
    $('.container .set').css({
      'transform': 'translate(27px)'
    });
    $('.fa-arrow-left').css({
      'transform': 'rotate(180deg)'
    });

    $('.fa-arrow-left').on('click', function() {
      $('.container .set').css({
        'transform': 'translate(220px)'
      });
      $('.fa-arrow-left').css({
        'transform': 'rotate(0deg)'
      });
    })
  });
})
```

Comment: It would help a lot to see a working version of the code, including your CSS and HTML. However I'd suggest looking in to using keyframes to do what you require.

Comment: How many times do you want your function to loop?  Do you want to loop your animations continuously?

Comment: You have the second onclick inside the first one. this will definitelly not going to work

Comment: @Pineda yes i do

Comment: your explanation is so confusing, by guessing I think you just want some toggle button, clicking on it will expand/collapse the left menu (back and forth). Here is the adjusted demo demonstrating the ***actual thing*** you need http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWOepz

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care if the code within the timer may take longer than your interval, use setInterval():

> setInterval(function, delay)

That fires the function passed in as first parameter over and over.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
// method to be executed;
}, 5000);  //Run the function every 5 seconds
```

A better approach is, to use setTimeout along with a self-executing anonymous function:

```
(function(){
// do some stuff
setTimeout(arguments.callee, 60000);
})();
```

that guarantees, that the next call is not made before your code was executed. I used arguments.callee in this example as function reference. It's a better way to give the function a name and call that within setTimeout because arguments.callee is deprecated in ecmascript 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with delay:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $('.fa-arrow-left').on('click', set_animation());
});
function set_animation()
{
      $('.container .set').css({
          'transform': 'translate(27px)'
      });
      $('.fa-arrow-left').css({
          'transform': 'rotate(180deg)'
      });
      $('.fa-arrow-left').on('click', function() {
          $('.container .set').css({
              'transform': 'translate(220px)'
          });
          $('.fa-arrow-left').css({
              'transform': 'rotate(0deg)'
          });
      });
      this.delay(800, setanimation);
}
```

This is called a "callback function". The idea is that it gets called when the function finishes.